# Zend_Loader include doesn't throw exception

Tags: zend-framework, exception, include, zend-loader

I am finding that when Zend tries to auto load a file which doesn't exist, it throws an error which I cannot catch in a try/catch block. This happens when I use `class_exists` too. I have fixed the problem by hacking zend:

```
if ($once) {
    if (!@include_once ($filename)) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to include $filename");
    }
    // include_once $filename;
}
else {
    if (!@include ($filename)) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to include $filename");
    }
    // include $filename;
}
```

The commented out lines are zend's originals. Now I can catch the exception thrown when a file cannot be included. Can anybody suggest a cleaner way to do this which doesn't involve hacking zend?

I am on Zend version 1.11.10, and the code in question is Zend_Loader line 146.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using include or include_once try using `Zend_Loader::loadClass()`

Here is the API: `Zend_Loader::loadClass($class, $dirs)`

An example:

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Container_Tree',
    array(
        '/home/production/mylib',
        '/home/production/myapp'
    )
);
```

Now the blurb on how it works:

> The string specifying the class is converted to a relative path by
>   substituting underscores with directory separators for your OS, and
>   appending *'.php'*. In the example above, *'Container_Tree'* becomes
>   *'Container\Tree.php'* on Windows.
>
> If *$dirs* is a string or an array, *Zend_Loader::loadClass()* searches
>   the directories in the order supplied. The first matching file is
>   loaded. If the file does not exist in the specified *$dirs*, then the
>   include_path for the PHP environment is searched.
>
> If the file is not found or the class does not exist after the load,
>   *Zend_Loader::loadClass()* throws a **Zend_Exception**.

This should allow you to use a try/catch block for any non-existent classes. Zend_Loader::loadFile() also has similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and autoload classes that don't exist. If for some reason the class you're trying to autoload may or may not be there, wrap that part of code with a `class_exists()` call.

I can't think of any reason why you would want `class_exists()` to throw an exception on failure since it's sole purpose is to allow you to check for the existence of classes.